# Julia (Julia-lang) How to get a subset of a dataframe and count the different activities by group?

Tags: julia

I am trying to get a subset of a dataframe.
The starting point have to be the first day of the current month.
The end point have to be the current day.
After that, I want to count the different activities by group.

The dataframe :

```
date        | activity

06-07-2020  | walking

06-07-2020  | rucking

07-07-2020  | tennis
...
```

I tried that :

```
DfName[Dates.firstdayofmonth(Dates.today()):Dates.today(), :]
```

Result :

```
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type Dates.Day
```

I also tried that :

```
combine(groupby(DfName, :activity), nrow => :count)    

@where(DfName, :date .>= Dates.firstdayofmonth(Dates.today()), :date .<= Dates.today())`
```

Result :

```
@where(DfName, :date .>= Dates.firstdayofmonth(Dates.today()), :date .<= Dates.today())
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Dates.Date, ::String)
Closest candidates are:
  isless(::DataValues.DataValue{Union{}}, ::Any) at /home/...
  isless(::PyObject, ::Any) at /home/...
```

How can I do that in Julia ?

Comment: For the next time, please take a minute to see how to properly format your code, data, and error messages (done it for you here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

```
filter(:date => x -> Dates.firstdayofmonth(Dates.today()) <= x <= Dates.today(), DfName)
```

or

```
filter(row -> Dates.firstdayofmonth(Dates.today()) <= row.x <= Dates.today(), DfName)
```

or

```
DfName[Dates.firstdayofmonth(Dates.today()) .<= DfName.date .<= Dates.today(), :]
```

or (soon in DataFrames.jl 1.0 release):

```
subset(DfName,
       :date => ByRow(>=(Dates.firstdayofmonth(Dates.today())),
       :date => ByRow(<=(Dates.today())
      )
```